# Efficient method to create pivoted/melted dataframes from larger dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe which a large set of columns (~36K) of which many are repeats of certain categorical information.

From this larger dataframe I would like to build essentially a relational set of dataframes.

I've laid out below the type of manipulation I'm hoping for.

```
Master df
ID    record_date    Site    Site1    Site2  Zip    Zip1   Zip2
1     12-01-1990     Site0   Site1    Site2  Zip0   Zip1   Zip2
1     12-12-1990     Site0   Site2    N/A    Zip0   Zip2   N/A
1     01-15-1991     Site0   Site2    Site3  Zip0   Zip2   Zip3
```

In the above example, I've shown site names and related zipcodes. My dataframe has a number of such columns which are related in a sequential manner, where depending on what "sites" where active at the record_date the underlying data may shift (e.g., I've shown Site1 dropping - becoming inactive - to later be replaced by site3)

I'd like the above dataframe to be transformed to:

```
Transformed df
ID    record_date    Site    Zip
1     12-01-1990     Site0   Zip0
1     12-01-1990     Site1   Zip1
1     12-01-1990     Site2   Zip2
1     12-12-1990     Site0   Zip0
1     12-12-1990     Site2   Zip2
1     01-15-1991     Site0   Zip0
1     01-15-1991     Site2   Zip2
1     01-15-1991     Site3   Zip3
```

As I have to do a fair number of transformations such as this, efficiency is key. I believe I can use functions such as pd.melt() or pd.pivot_table(), but I haven't been able to arrive at the exact setup below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
df=df.rename(columns={'Site':'Site0','Zip':'Zip0'})

pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['Site','Zip'],i='index',j='Drop',sep='').dropna(0).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[330]: 
   ID record_date   Site   Zip
0   1  12-01-1990  Site0  Zip0
1   1  12-01-1990  Site1  Zip1
2   1  12-01-1990  Site2  Zip2
3   1  12-12-1990  Site0  Zip0
4   1  12-12-1990  Site2  Zip2
5   1  01-15-1991  Site0  Zip0
6   1  01-15-1991  Site2  Zip2
7   1  01-15-1991  Site3  Zip3
```

Comment: @wingsoficarus116 yw ~ :-) happy coding